# HCE Service is not running

Tags: android, nfc, apdu, pcsc, hce

I installed aide from playstore and copied the code from google to test the HostApduService. My app is shown under Tapp and Pay but if I send a CAPDU with my identive cloud 4700f reader my phone LG G2 (android 4.4.2) is not responding anything. My reader is blinking and pcsc tells card is connected. It seems that the service is never started but I don't know why. Does anybody had the same problem and hopefully a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a general problem with Android HCE on the LG G2 (see this [blog](http://www.droid-life.com/2014/04/09/lg-g2-on-att-receiving-update-to-fix-google-wallet-tap-pay-issues/)). So I would assume that HCE is not avaliable on the G2 with Android 4.4.2 but will be part of the next update.

Comment: Thank you very much for that information. That would explain my problems. I will ask LG if that problem occurs on the german Vodafone version too. I got an update last week but in the changelog was nothing about google wallet.

Comment: After conversion with the german lg support, it seems that it is a bug in the lg implementation of kitkat and it seems that lg can't fix it because their developer department is in korea. I don't know why this is a reason but this was the answer from lg.